# Declaring the value of a string based on a given text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, windows-forms-designer

I'm quite new to programming so I'm gonna ask about how I can declare the value of a string based on an object text.

So based on the title.Text of my interface. I am going to determine the string value. Here is the code that I tried:

```
 public Mainmenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initializeOffice();

    }
    public string office;

    public void initializeOffice()
    {
        if (officeName.Text == "Accounting Office")
        {
            office = "Accounting";
        } else if (officeName.Text == "Registrar's Office")
        {
            office = "Registrar";
        }
```

I am using the office string as a variable to determine my folder paths because both Accounting and Registrar Offices have different directories. Example:

```
using (StreamWriter objWriter = File.AppendText("C:Desktop\\" + office + "\\Finished\\" + ticketNumber.Text +".txt"))
```

Can anyone help me out? It seems that the string office always shows "Accounting" value even if the office text is already different.

Additional:

```
if (chooseService.Text == "")
                     {
                     MessageBox.Show("Please specify the department.");
                     }
                   else
                     {
                       this.Hide();
                       Mainmenu login = new Mainmenu();

                       login.Show();
                       login.officeName.Text = chooseService.Text;
                     }
```

This is where the content of my officeName is fetched. The chooseService object is a comboBox with choices of different offices.

Comment: What is the default/start-up value of officeName.Text you have defined in the designer? when is it set to the desired string (Accounting Office/Registrar's Office)?

Comment: It is based on the login screen of my little program. Where a user must choose the department when he/she logs in and based on the choice the officeName will be displayed on the Main Menu. So I also wanted to store the files into different folders for different offices, depending on the login choice. It is like a program to be used for two different offices.

Comment: You may want to search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+get+value+from+textbox and see how to get values from textbox... The code you have would work if you actually call it when you give user chance to type in a value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that you MainMenu form is initialising the title before you are setting the string it will use to determine what 'office' should be set to.

try this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chooseService.Text))
  MessageBox.Show("Please specify the department.");
else
{
  this.Hide();
  MainMenu login = new MainMenu(chooseService.Text);
  login.Show();
}
```

Then modify your MainMenu form like so:

```
public Mainmenu(string department)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initializeOffice(department);

}
public string office;

public void initializeOffice(string department)
{
    if (department == "Accounting Office")
    {
        office = "Accounting";
    } else if (department == "Registrar's Office")
    {
        office = "Registrar";
    }
```

This will guarantee your main menu class has the information it needs to display the correct value (or use to set the path). You could also move the initialisation of the title out of the constructor of the MainMenu class and call initailiszeOffice with the string value from chooseService.Text, either will work bvut I prefer the code supplied. Neater IMO.

Comment: Really strange replacement for reading value from a textbox on a form... You may want to explain what question you actually tried to answer with this code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what do you mean? The user selects an item from a combo, the text of which is passed to the MainMenu form to initialize the office field which is used in a folder path. There seemed to be an assumption made that simply setting a textbox's text value would magically call initialzeOffice method. The solution is either the above code or to call initializeOffice() after setting the text box's text property. Happy to be corrected if I am missing something.

Comment: I see now... Question has absolutely nothing to do with what OP actually needed which seem to be  "pass value to form" as you answered, but asking for reading value of text field... You may want to work together with OP on aligning question and answer...

Comment: Did you also modify the constructors signature to require a string parameter? what error are you getting?

Comment: (CodexNZ, if you don't provide @ in the comment no one will be notified if there is more than one commenter)